# How to make 2 touch sensors move one servo?

Tags: arduino

I want to make 2 touch sensors do the same thing which is to move the servo.
If either touch sensor is touched the motor moves up or down depending on it's previous position.
The second touch sensor should be named TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2

here is the code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

    const int TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN   = 6;   // Arduino pin connected to touch sensor's pin
    const int SERVO_PIN          = 9;   // Arduino pin connected to servo motor's pin
    
    Servo servo; // create servo object to control a servo
    
    // variables will change:
    int angle = 141;           // the current angle of servo motor
    int lastTouchState;      // the previous state of touch sensor
    int currentTouchState;   // the current state of touch sensor
    
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial
      pinMode(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);
      servo.attach(SERVO_PIN);       // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
    
      servo.write(angle);
      currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      lastTouchState    = currentTouchState;  // save the last state
      currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);  //read new state 
    
      if(lastTouchState == LOW && currentTouchState == HIGH) {
    
        // change angle of servo motor
        if(angle == 141)
          angle = 156;
        else
        if(angle == 156)
          angle = 141;
    
    
        // control servo motor arccoding to the angle
        servo.write(angle);
        
    
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this should work. Please replace `<pin number>` with the number of the pin to which your second touch sensor is connected.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN   = 6;   // Arduino pin connected to touch sensor's pin
const int TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2   = <pin number>;
const int SERVO_PIN          = 9;   // Arduino pin connected to servo motor's pin

Servo servo; // create servo object to control a servo

// variables will change:
int angle = 141;           // the current angle of servo motor
int lastTouchState;      // the previous state of touch sensor
int currentTouchState;   // the current state of touch sensor
int lastTouchState2;      // the previous state of touch sensor 2
int currentTouchState2;   // the current state of touch sensor 2


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // initialize serial
  pinMode(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2, INPUT);
  servo.attach(SERVO_PIN);       // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object

  servo.write(angle);
  currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);
  currentTouchState2 = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2);
}

void loop() {
  lastTouchState    = currentTouchState;  // save the last state
  currentTouchState = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN);  //read new state 
  
  lastTouchState2    = currentTouchState2;  // save the last state
  currentTouchState2 = digitalRead(TOUCH_SENSOR_PIN2);  //read new state 

  if((lastTouchState == LOW && currentTouchState == HIGH) || (lastTouchState2 == LOW && currentTouchState2 == HIGH)) {

    // change angle of servo motor
    if(angle == 141)
      angle = 156;
    else
    if(angle == 156)
      angle = 141;


    // control servo motor arccoding to the angle
    servo.write(angle);
    

      }
  }
```